# What does $c.c.$ mean in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

[This is a proof from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Least-squares_minimization) of Moore-Penrose inverse being the optimal solution of a least squares problem, in which there is a acronym $c.c.$ occurred in some of the equations. Mind if I ask what does that represent?

Comment: Complex Conjugate

Answer (score 4):

It means complex conjugate (of the term preceeding it), but in my opinion it is very lazy notation, for example, line 1 reads
\begin{align*}
  \|Ax-b\|^2 & = \|Az - b + Ax - Az\|^2\\
             &= \|Az - b\|^2 + (Az - b)^*(Ax - Az) + \overline{(Az - b)^*(Ax - Az)} + \|A(x - z)\|^2
\end{align*}

Comment: It might be lazy in this case, but if you are doing some nasty algebra, it's very convenient. See Olver's _Asymptotics and Special Functions_ chapter on Liouville-Green transform and see what I mean :)

Comment: Might be. I don't have a copy at hand, but I prefer $2\Re z$ over $z + \text{c.c.}$.

Comment: It's just a matter of style I guess. I'd use the c.c. notation to imply that not much attention should be payed to that term, as is just the _complex conjugate_. I can say that -for me- this is not the case.